# PutFile append file

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there is a way in NiFi to use a processor such as "PutFile" and have it write to one single file (append data to this file, or over-write the data in this file) - rather than create multiple different files?

Is there another processor I need to use in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Hey, Can you help with your solution for this requirement? I am new to Nifi and stuck with similar problem, I doubt if NiFi still have any ready made solution for this. Any quick references would be appreciated. Regards,

Comment: @ChauhanB i had solved this problem by creating my own custom processor. Not sure if there is an OOTB solution as of yet... i had asked this question a few years ago - perhaps things have changed. Good luck!

Comment: this is pretty old but i thought someone should answer this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to append data to a file but you can overwrite the file using PutFile.

The PutFile processor writes a file to disk using the the attribute "filename" on the FlowFile. So if you put an UpdateAttribute processor before a PutFile that updates all incoming FlowFiles with to same "filename" then the PutFile processor will write them all with the same file name on disk.

To do this with PutFile, make sure you configure processor property "Conflict Resolution Strategy" to "Replace".

Comment: As per my verification "replace" conflict resolution strategy does not APPEND but actually REPLACES the content in file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but that's stated in the first line of the answer and answers what's asked in the question "(append data to this file, or over-write the data in this file)".

Answer (score 8):

**For those who don't want to override the data in the file, but want to append data**.

**Appending to single file Using ExecuteStreamCommand processor**:

It isn't possible with putFile processor, but you can use the [ExecuteStreamCommand](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) processor to accomplish this.

In command arguments, put the attributes you want to log, separated by delimiter `${aatr1};${aatr2};${attr3}`.

In the command path, add the absolute path of a Bash script: /path/logger.sh

**logger.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1|$2|$3" >> /path/attributes.log
```

File *attibutres.log* will append the three attributes line by line. Make sure that the Bash script is executable with NiFi.

Do a `chmod 777 logger.sh` ([a+rwx](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/)).

**Appending to single file Using ExecuteScript Processor**:

Try this ECMAScript code:

```javascript
var flowFile = session.get();
var File = Java.type("java.io.RandomAccessFile");
if (flowFile != null) {
    var filename = flowFile.getAttribute("filename");
    /// write to file
    var filePath = "/path/attributes.log" ;
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filePath", filePath);
     var file = new File(filePath, "rws");
     file.seek(file.length());
        file.write(filename.getBytes());
        file.write("\n".getBytes());
        file.close();
    // Finish by transferring the FlowFile to an output relationship
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: the `ExecuteStreamCommand` or `ExecuteScript` processor had better be single threaded, I guess

Answer (score 2):

LogAttribute processor may be an option, because it appears that it offers the closest functionality to a file append. But it doesn't appear to be ideal, as it offers few options for directing the output.

There are two other options you can try if you are intent on using the "out of the box" processor functionality rather than developing classes to customize. Use an ExecuteScript processor to execute a Jython, Groovy, or JS, script that modifies the output flowFile to include only the Attributes you need. Follow that with a PutMongo or a PutSQL processor to update a persisted database resource.

Another option if you don't have a database resource at your disposal: use the ExecuteScript processor mentioned above, followed by a PutFile that outputs a uniquely named filename attribute to a directory - say, ${filename}.${uuid}. You'll wind up with a large number of similarly formatted files - one log record per file - which you can then roll up into one file for analysis using Linux line commands or alternatively employ a final ExecuteScript processor in your workflow to roll up every time a file gets processed through your workflow. This last one may not be a good idea, as it is not clear whether it will introduce synchronization and write contention problems if your stream of flowFiles is high.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful for people who are looking for "out of the box" processors to do this task as you mentioned in your response. I actually solved this by creating a custom processor

Comment: Hey Bigbug, Can you help with your solution for this requirement? I am new to Nifi and stuck with similar problem, I doubt if NiFi still have any ready made solution for this. Any quick references would be appreciated. Regards

Comment: @56lt56 I've mentioned executescript solution in my answer

Answer (score 1):

The original question was to append to an existing file. Presumably the idea is to write one line for each flowfile.

You can achieve this use case with a different approach: instead of appending successive lines to a file, do the merging in Nifi and then write out the entire file in one go. This is done with the MergeContent processor. It takes the content of successive flowfiles, and pastes them together into a single flowfile. It has various configuration options to say how many flowfiles you want to accumulate before it spits out the merged result, which you can then write out using PutFile.

Here is a recipe to write out key attributes in CSV format to a hardcoded location. **Use case: archive flowfile attributes before emptying a queue.**

Suppose you want to write out the attributes `id`, `name` and `size`.

- Add a processor AttributesToCSV. Set "Attribute list" to `id,name,size`.
- Set "Destination" to "flowfile-content".
- Connect it downstream to a MergeContent.
- Set "Minimum/Maximum Number of Entries" so that your entire queue fits into one bin (e.g. 1 and some large number, respectively)
- Set "Delimiter strategy" to "Text"
- Set "Demarcator" to a newline (type <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd>, or paste in the newline)
- In "Header" set an appropriate CSV header e.g. "ID,Name,Size" and add a trailing newline
- Set "Max bin age" to a few seconds - long enough that it has time to merge everything, but short enough that you are happy to wait.
- Connect it downstream to an UpdateAttribute that sets `filename` attribute to whatever you like
- Connect that downstream to a PutFile, set the "Directory" property

Everything else can stay as defaults.

This recipe needs adapting for other use cases:

- if there is a constant flow that needs to be written out: split into bins by number of entries, and make the filename dynamic - e.g. UpdateAttribute can set `filename` to `${UUID().csv}`
- if another format than CSV is desired: replace the AttributesToCSV by some other processor

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a custom processor that append the content of FlowFiles (as string) to the end of a file that previously exists.

**GitHub repository**: https://github.com/JavDomGom/nifi-custom-processors/tree/main

Once you compile the [NAR](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/NiFi+Components) and add it to the NiFi "lib" folder, you can test it by following these steps:

1. Create the following NiFi Flow.

   [image: 01]
2. **GenerateFlowFile** processor configuration.

   [image: 02]
3. **UpdateAttribute** processor configuration.

   [image: 03]
4. **PutFile** processor configuration.

   [image: 04]
5. **AppendToFile** custom processor configuration.

   [image: 05]
6. When starting NiFi Flow you can see that the first time the **PutFile** processor will create the file and the FlowFile will come out through the "*success*" relationship.

   [image: 06]
7. The second and subsequent times, **PutFile** will fail (that's how it is configured in properties), because the file to write (testFile.txt) already exists in the destination path. This is not a problem; it is just what we need for the FlowFile to be redirected through the "*failure*" relationship to the custom processor **AppendTofile**.

   [image: 07]
8. The three queued FlowFiles come out through the "*success*" relationship.

   [image: 08]
9. Finally, inspect the destination file to check if it has added each FlowFile as a string at the end of the file.

   [image: 09]

I have also recorded some videos explaining how to do it step by step:

- [Apache NiFi: Develop custom processor (Spanish audio, English subtitles)](https://youtu.be/LfiUmvOHgPo)
- [Apache NiFi: Develop custom processor AppendToFile (Spanish audio)](https://youtu.be/WXxvAxEgxgQ)

You can also collaborate in the repository; it has a Free Software license.

Answer (score 0):

There are one or more solutions for appending data to a file. I prefer the ExecuteGroovyScript processor for file appending.you can get the file through groovy script easily. then if file exists we can append the data. I successfully implement this method.